# How to get bluetooth device mac address by stored device name

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to android and I am new here too.

I want to know if android api provides some methods to get bluetooth mac address using previous stored bluetooth device name? I searched many examples here and from internet and most of them using list format to show both device name and mac address, what I need is to get one mac address by a known device name.

Thanks in advance if someone here can help me.

Yman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible.You can't get the mac address only from a known device name.The bluetooth device name is not the key element for the bluetooth connection and communication,but the mac address will be.Only you can get the mac address according to the device name if you has pre-stored the related BluetoothDevice object and the name is different from the others.